# How and why does one come up with inequalities such as $(n!)^2\leq n^n(n!)<(2n)!\;$?

Tags: combinatorics, factorial

I just began with combinatorics and so far, I've done nothing more than learn about the definition of the factorial and do a few questions based on it, one of which was this :

> Prove that $\forall n\in\Bbb Z^+, (n!)^2\leq n^n(n!)<(2n)!$

I was wondering how and why one comes up with seemingly weird inequalities like these.

Pardon me if my question sounds absurd.

Thank You!

Comment: Note that the outer inequality follows from $\frac{(2n)!}{n!n!}={2n\choose n}>1$. All in all we simply have $\prod_{k=1}^nk\prod_{k=1}^nk\le \prod_{k=1}^nn\prod_{k=1}^nk<\prod_{k=1}^nk\prod_{k=1}^n(n+k)$

Comment: Have you learned about the combinatorial intepretation of factorials and exponentiation?

Comment: @Phicar Unfortunately, not yet...

Comment: @RajdeepSindhu Then you are stuck with the arithmetical interpretations. This becomes much more interesting when you are dealing with structures instead of just numbers :).

Comment: https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1539/explorers-of-dark,, i can chat here

Answer (score 0):

Identities like these are usually discovered by playing with strings of numbers. That's also a good way to discover the intuition behind the identity. For example take $n = 6$. The three expressions are:

$A = \left(6!\right)^2 = \left(1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot4\cdot5\cdot6\right)^2$

$B = 6^6 \left(6!\right) = \left(6\cdot6\cdot6\cdot6\cdot6\cdot6\right)\left(1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot4\cdot5\cdot6\right)$

$C = \left(2\cdot6\right)! = 1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot4\cdot5\cdot6\cdot7\cdot8\cdot9\cdot10\cdot11\cdot12$

We can go from $A$ to $B$ by replacing one of the $1$s with $6$, and one of the $2$s with $6$, ... and one of the $6$s with $6$. Each of these makes the number bigger, so $A \leq B$.

Similarly, we can go from $B$ to $C$ by replacing one of the $6$s in the first group with $7$, and one of the $6$s in the first group with $8$, ... and the last one of the $6$s in the first group with $12$. Each of these makes the number bigger, so $B \lt C$.

THIS IS NOT A PROOF but it shows WHY the identity is true.